# Migrating from Oracle to MySQL using WorkBench Migration Tool

Tags: mysql, oracle, migration, mysql-workbench

I am currently migrating from Oracle to MySQL and I am going to use the  migration tool in workbench to help me with the procedure. I have entered my source connection details as follows:

```
Database System: Generic RDBMS 
Connection Method: ODBC(Manually Entered parameters)
Driver:Oracle RDB driver
Hostname: 127.0.0.1  Port:1521
Username: user
Database:db
```

But I seem to be receiving the following error when testing the connection:

```
ERROR: Error during Connect to source DBMS: Error("('HY093', '[HY093] [Oracle][ODBC]
[Rdb]Invalid parameter number. (-2000) (SQLDriverConnect);

[HY093] [Oracle][ODBC][Rdb]Invalid parameter number. (-2000)')"):
error calling Python module function DbGenericRE.connect
```

I am struggling to figure out what parameter is wrong, any one have an idea what could be causing this?